# I got this error "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Tags: vb.net

It seems the problem on my code is the SQL query, I don't know if my query is correct

I've been looking for the right query on this but I haven't found a solution

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table(userName, userCity) VALUES('" + 
        TextBox1.Text + "' , '" + TextBox2.Text + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Recorded Successfully")

End Sub
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Comment: You need to provide that name of the table.  If your table really is named 'Table' then change it immediately.  Like every identifier, table names should be descriptive.  A table that stores user data should most likely be named 'User' or 'Users', depending on whether you conventionally use singular or plural names for tables.  I use singular because I treat them like a class name but many people use plural, because a table contains multiple records.  Either way, pick a convention and stick to it.

Comment: There may be times where using a reserved word for an identifier is justified.  In such cases, you need to escape the name in code, which means wrapping it in brackets, e.g. `[Date]`.  There's no justification for using 'Table' as a table name though.

Comment: Also, it's very bad that you are using string concatenation to insert values directly into your SQL code.  That can cause all sorts of problems, the most serious of which could result in the loss of all your data.  Learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET ASAP.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the help, i made what you have said that ill change the table name and it works.  I am very new at .net and i am still processing in learning because this is my requirement on my job. Again thanks for the help